# Alternative to xmlrpc_encode_request

Tags: php, xml, xml-rpc

As I am unable to install XML-RPC on localhost I would like to know if there are any PHP alternative to [`xmlrpc_encode_request()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-encode-request.php) that will help me to complete my assignment.

Comment: I have to ask why you "can't" install xmlrpc on local host? Is it giving you trouble? Or are you not permitted to install it?

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that there is a good structure of the XML to be output, you might try out using the [`XMLWriter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) extension of PHP to do the work for you.

Take care to the comment the page says:

> Important: `XMLWriter` expects UTF-8 data from you. It can output XML in various encodings, but input should be strictly UTF-8!

Example usage code (taken from documentation of [`XMLWriter::openMemory`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-open-memory.php)):

```
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');

$oXMLWriter = new XMLWriter;
$oXMLWriter->openMemory();
$oXMLWriter->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$oXMLWriter->startElement('test');
$oXMLWriter->text('Hello, World!');
$oXMLWriter->endElement();

$oXMLWriter->endDocument();
echo $oXMLWriter->outputMemory(TRUE);
```

Also, please note that the usage of [`xmlrpc_encode_request()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-encode-request.php) is on one's own responsibility as the function is experimental and subject to change.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, at the end i used PEAR class so i did not tried your method but im sure will work

Answer (score 0):

I ended using PEAR XML_RPC http://pear.php.net/package/XML_RPC
I did not try Whisperity method as i was already dealing with this when he answered.

To make it work i just installed like:

```
 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/pear install XML_RPC
```

Then i used :

```
$content = new XML_RPC_Value(array(
            'post_title'=> new XML_RPC_Value($title,'string'),
            'post_status'=> new XML_RPC_Value('publish','string'),
            'post_excerpt'=> new XML_RPC_Value($title,'string'),
            'post_content'=> new XML_RPC_Value($body,'string'),
            'mt_allow_comments'=> new XML_RPC_Value(0,'int'),
            'mt_allow_pings'=> new XML_RPC_Value(0,'int'),
            'post_type'=> new XML_RPC_Value('market','string')
        ),'struct' );    
$params = array(new XML_RPC_Value(0,'int'),new XML_RPC_Value($this->UserName,'string'),new XML_RPC_Value($this->PassWord,'string'),$content,new XML_RPC_Value(true,'boolean'));
```

Comment: Well, this method is usable only if PHAR is enabled on the server. Also, if this was the solution to your question, mark it as the answer.